# change the color of many layers in gimp

Tags: colors, gimp

how can I change the color of many layers fast? Every layer is mostly transparent with an black icon

[image: mostly transparent with an black icon]

[image: This is what my layers look like].

At first, how can I even change the color? I tried so many things but nothing can do it right. I just want to change it to a specific color code and keep the details on the edges.

Is there also a way to do it for all layers?

Comment: You wish to change the color of the icons or the background? And if it's the background, you mean you want to disable transparency for each layer?

Comment: I want to change the icon. Like the black to another color